# Failed to insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, kernel-modules

I've just installed fedora 27 with all updates on my new laptop. And I've  tried to install VirutalBox.

I've installed this packages:

- VirtualBox
- VirtualBox-kmodsrc
- VirtualBox-server
- VirtualBox-akmod

and when I open dnfdragora also get installed

- kmod-VirtualBox-4.15.6-300.fc27.x86_64

that one I think is built for my kernel because that's the the version of current kernel and packages in dnfdragora don't have versions in names.

and when I've try to run the VM I got this error:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is probably not
loaded.You may not have kernel driver installed for kernel that is 
runnig, if so you may do as root: dnf install akmod-VirtualBox kernel-
devel-$(uname -r)If you installed VirtualBox packages and don't want 
reboot the system, you may need load the kernel driver, doing as root: 
akmods; systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - 
The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

and when I've executed `systemctl restart systemd-modules-load` it failed and the output of `journalctl -xe` look like this:

```
-- Subject: Rozpoczęto uruchamianie jednostki systemd-modules-load.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Jednostka systemd-modules-load.service rozpoczęła uruchamianie.
mar 07 18:17:09 jcubic systemd-modules-load[25233]: Failed to insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available
mar 07 18:17:09 jcubic systemd-modules-load[25233]: Failed to insert 'vboxnetflt': Required key not available
mar 07 18:17:09 jcubic systemd-modules-load[25233]: Failed to insert 'vboxnetadp': Required key not available
mar 07 18:17:09 jcubic systemd-modules-load[25233]: Failed to insert 'vboxpci': Required key not available
mar 07 18:17:09 jcubic systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mar 07 18:17:09 jcubic systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
-- Subject: Jednostka systemd-modules-load.service się nie powiodła
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Jednostka systemd-modules-load.service się nie powiodła.
-- 
-- Wynik: failed.
```

I have rpm fusion enabled but all packages was from @system repository (as indicated in dnfdragora)

I've also tried to reboot, with no effect.

I've also try to follow instruction from article [VirtualBox 5.2 on Fedora 27/26, CentOS/RHEL 7.4/6.9](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-with-yum-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

but command `/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup` give this output:

vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

dmesg don't show any errors related to VirtualBox or kernel drivers but I have errors about pcieport and ACPI but I don't know if they're related.

Comment: ...and what does "dmesg" tell about the problem? A look into my cloudy crystal ball tells me that maybe you have "Secure Boot" enabled in your BIOS. If this is the case, you need to disable it since otherwise the vboxdrv driver will not be loaded.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt yes I have secure boot, do I need to install again windows and Linux after I disable it because I have efi fedora installation? Is there a way to have VBox in secure boot? Maybe create signature somehow.

Comment: I've found another question on askubuntu about UEFI and VBox https://askubuntu.com/questions/914997/install-virtualbox-while-keeping-secure-boot

Comment: No, you don't need to reinstall Windows or Linux after disabling Secure Boot.

Comment: I was not able to make it work with secure boot because the modules where missing so there was nothing to sign, but disabling UEFI work.